# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working until scroll iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

After fetch data,i reload tableview. I use automatic dimension
 don't override heightForRowAtIndexPath like below

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200; 
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Everything is ok in iOS9. But in iOS8 appear like following link until scroll.
[iOS8 appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5YEk.png)

I tried:

1. `[_tableView setNeedsLayout];`  `[_tableView layoutIfNeeded];`  `[_tableView reloadData];` After that occur else ui issue in iPhone 6Plus.
2. I set preferred Width automatic and not marker explicit.
3. I set uitableviewcell accessory type none.
4. Tried reload section.
5. Tried after did display cell, reload table view. After that while scrolling another view controller in page controller, occur same issue.
6. Tried [cell layoutIfNeeded]
7. Tried setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth

Comment: [yourLabel setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:tableView.frame.size.width]; might be work

Comment: I tried and still work same. The cell have labels, image, not only label.

Comment: I am using the same I have 2 labels and image in cell, can you share your autolayout constraint, there might be issue in autolayout setting

Comment: [1]: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/ztvPu.png]
[2]: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAYKc.png]                                                      [3]: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/dmjbf.png]                                                        [4]: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/jhZXd.png]

Comment: have you set label number of line = 0 ? or not?

Comment: Yes, that s running in iOS9 perfect, the issue for iOS8

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload data in `viewDidappear` or `viewWillappear` and check your constraints that it is perfect or not because `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` strongly recommended autolayout.

Update :

According to comments try to add this two line in `cellforrowAtindexpath`

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

In order to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view. If you missing like this then check that

hope this 
will help :)

Comment: i also tried, but when in viewdidappear, data have not fetched yet, so reload again after fetch data. i also checked constraints. if constraints have been fail, i think that have not run perfect in iOS9 all devices. The issue occur in iOS8.:/

Comment: have you tried for different devices or simulator running ios 9 ?

Comment: i have tried iPhone 6, 6plus,5s and simulator iOS9 everything is perfect. I also use Page Controller maybe that cause of the issue.

Comment: First add only one line `[cell layoutIfNeeded];` not  `[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];` untill require. if you got result by only layoutifneeded then no need to add updateConstraintifneeded

Comment: I tried both of them and only layoutIfNeeded, i got same result:/

Comment: And you should reload data in `viewdidappear` and you can add notification like addobserver when your content size changed reload tabledata. like this link https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-8-self-sizing-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-type/

Comment: I added "UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification" notification but selector (onContentSizeChange:) is not called.

Comment: that means your content size is not changing or there is some mistake to add notification